# Write in cell of an table

Tags: java, apache-poi

How I can write into merged cells of a table without clearing the line or clearing the table's border.

before

[image: before]

after execution of the IDE

[image: after execution of the IDE]

that is my code

```
 Row r5 = sh.createRow(29);
 c = r5.createCell(1);
 c.setCellValue((String) jTable1.getValueAt(0, 5)+"E");
 c.setCellStyle(Style);
 //LatitudeB

 c = r5.createCell(4);
 c.setCellValue((String) jTable1.getValueAt(0, 6)+"N");
 c.setCellStyle(Style);
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge cells and set value at the same time by using Apache POI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228761/how-to-merge-cells-and-set-value-at-the-same-time-by-using-apache-poi)

Comment: My problem is different the merged cells are already created just i need to write in cell without cleaning the line or cleaning the border of cell like the example of my issue

Comment: The create methods `createRow` and `createCell` are doing exactly what they say. They are creating **new**  rows and cells. If you wants to change existing rows and cells, you need the get methods `getRow`and `getCell`.

Comment: In need to set a value in an existen cell no to get a value from a cell

Comment: You need the existing cell. Get it using `getRow`and `getCell`. Then set the cell value of that cell using `setCellValue`.

Comment: Ok tnx i have  try get Row and cell for to set value and it work tnx axel :)